# @objc annotation on the classname vs the class itself

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge

Say I have a class called `ExampleClass`.

Say I then write code like so:

`@objc class ExampleClass: NSObject {}`

With an ObjectiveC file header like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ExampleClass, NSObject)
@end
```

Which I then consume in my React Native app like so:
`console.log('exampleClass', React.NativeModules.ExampleClass);`

Now compiling with `react-native run-ios` produces the following exceptions:

```
❌  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
> Symbol: `_OBJC_CLASS_$_ExampleClass`
> Referenced from: `l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_ExampleClass_$_RCTExternModule in ExampleClass-2517576D7E90370.o



❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **
```

While changing only the swift so that it reads:

```
@objc(ExampleClass)
class ExampleClass: NSObject {}
```

results in successful compilation. What is the difference between those two syntaxes? Why is the latter working while the former is not?

Comment: I think that `@objc(ExampleClass)` defines the class name to be `ExampleClass`, instead of the name mangled name wift would produce (e.g. `_OBJC_CLASS_$_ExampleClass`)

Comment: Thanks! If you write that up as an answer I'll update/accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to that `@objc` attribute specifies the name Swift will export to Objective C.

> ## Configuring Swift Interfaces in Objective-C
>
> In some cases, you need finer grained control over how your Swift API is exposed to Objective-C. You can use the `@objc(name)` attribute
>   to change the name of a class, property, method, enumeration type, or
>   enumeration case declaration in your interface as it’s exposed to
>   Objective-C code.
>
> For example, if the name of your Swift class contains a character that isn’t supported by Objective-C, you can provide an alternative
>   name to use in Objective-C. If you provide an Objective-C name for a
>   Swift function, use Objective-C selector syntax. Remember to add a
>   colon (`:`) wherever a parameter follows a selector piece.

From [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 4.1) > Swift Type Compatibility > Configuring Swift Interfaces in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35)